# Handlebars helpers to check active class

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I want to check if my current element is active

```
{{each}}
<div class="num">{{#isActive this}} show this {{/isActive}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

I created this handlebars template

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isActive', function(element, options){
    if($(element).hasClass('active')){
         return options.fn(this);
    }
    return options.inverse(this);
});
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handlebars is a string-based templater, which means it works with and outputs strings only. Handlebars doesn't know anything about your environment (which is DOM in the case). So, `this` in template is just a current context object (template's data), not a DOM node.

You can't doing any kinds of DOM checks in the template or helper. In Handlebars such checks should be context-based, which means you should pass already prepared data to your template and then simply use `#if` statement:

```
{{each}}
<div class="num">{{#if isActive}} show this {{else}} show that {{/if}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

The good practice when using Handlebars or other logic-less templates is to storing current template's state somewhere and work only with it. You get DOM event => update state => re-render template, you get data changed (by AJAX for example) => update state => re-render template, and so on.

State could be a Model in the MVC terminology, or be such a separate entity, it doesn't matter. The key idea is to keeping state out of the template itself and manipulate it only in application. It's core concept of logic-less approach, IMO.

By the way, there is Handlebars fork called [HTMLBars](https://github.com/tildeio/htmlbars), which works with DOMFragments instead of strings. Take a look, maybe it's what you'll be happy with.